# Timefold: Is tailChainSwap incompatible with change and swap?

Tags: java, optaplanner, timefold

I'm trying this configuration

```
<unionMoveSelector>
  <changeMoveSelector>
  </changeMoveSelector>
  <swapMoveSelector>
  </swapMoveSelector>
  <tailChainSwapMoveSelector>
  </tailChainSwapMoveSelector>
</unionMoveSelector>
```

But according to log (debug level) only tailChainSwap was picked.

I have tried to set probability of tailChainSwap to extremely low value.

```
<unionMoveSelector>
  <changeMoveSelector>
    <fixedProbabilityWeight>1 </fixedProbabilityWeight>
  </changeMoveSelector>
  <swapMoveSelector>
    <fixedProbabilityWeight>1 </fixedProbabilityWeight>
  </swapMoveSelector>
  <tailChainSwapMoveSelector>
    <fixedProbabilityWeight>0.001 </fixedProbabilityWeight>
  </tailChainSwapMoveSelector>
</unionMoveSelector>
```

But still only tailChainSwap was picked.

Configuration file is working, because if I set fixedProbabilityWeight to 0, I can get rid of tailChainSwap.

My timefold version: 1.3.0

Comment: This is interesting behavior; I would expect the regular change and swap moves to be picked more often. That said, there are many possible reasons why that didn't happen; maybe none were doable, maybe tail chain swaps resulted in better scores... That is impossible to know from the information in the question.

Answer (score 1):

Looks like I was too hurry.
Change and swap was in the log but very rarely.
There were only picked move in the log, change and swap were picked very rarely.

Comment: Where you looking at the DEBUG or TRACE log? The DEBUG log shows only the winning moves. The TRACE log shows all the selected moves too.

Comment: Yes, I was looking in DEBUG log.

Comment: It's possible that only tailchain moves were winning, but selection was fair/correct.