# Timefold: does tailChainSwap print wrong move information to the log?

Tags: java, optaplanner, timefold

I'm trying to solve tsp-problem with timefold.

I've got a [many tailChainSwap moves](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77606604/timefold-is-tailchainswap-incompatible-with-change-and-swap) in the log, which didn't change the score.

I tried to understand what is happening using [this approach](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29405153/step-changes-listener-in-construction-heuristic-phase)

And it turned out that each move reversed the entire chain except anchor. ([0, 1, 2, 3] -> [0, 3, 2, 1])

But in the log these moves didn't look like that.

For example there was a move (56 {31} <-tailChainSwap-> 10 {75}), which turned

0, 65, 86, 58, 27, 31, 56, 75, 10, 81, 73, 95, 78, 67, 98, 61, 89, 2, 50, 34, 76, 64, 62, 28, 13, 69, 91, 4, 16, 96, 80, 14, 26, 29, 55, 3, 24, 71, 57, 66, 74, 39, 83, 7, 47, 37, 77, 88, 87, 20, 5, 92, 54, 35, 21, 32, 11, 99, 44, 43, 40, 25, 19, 70, 72, 84, 51, 17, 79, 38, 90, 8, 22, 52, 18, 9, 53, 42, 48, 68, 41, 59, 63, 85, 6, 23, 49, 82, 94, 30, 46, 45, 36, 1, 60, 33, 97, 15, 93, 12

to

0, 12, 93, 15, 97, 33, 60, 1, 36, 45, 46, 30, 94, 82, 49, 23, 6, 85, 63, 59, 41, 68, 48, 42, 53, 9, 18, 52, 22, 8, 90, 38, 79, 17, 51, 84, 72, 70, 19, 25, 40, 43, 44, 99, 11, 32, 21, 35, 54, 92, 5, 20, 87, 88, 77, 37, 47, 7, 83, 39, 74, 66, 57, 71, 24, 3, 55, 29, 26, 14, 80, 96, 16, 4, 91, 69, 13, 28, 62, 64, 76, 34, 50, 2, 89, 61, 98, 67, 78, 95, 73, 81, 10, 75, 56, 31, 27, 58, 86, 65

Is it a wrong information in the log, or do I not understand how tailChainSwap suppose to work on the same chain?

(upd) example was changed

(upd2) A few last strings of log:

```
2023-12-06 17:20:43,267 DEBUG [ai.tim.sol.cor.imp.loc.DefaultLocalSearchPhase] (main)     LS step (17493), time spent (60088), score (0hard/-20852279soft),     best score (0hard/-20852279soft), accepted/selected move count (1/148), picked move (84 {51} <-tailChainSwap-> 70 {72}).
>>>0, 12, 93, 15, 97, 33, 60, 1, 36, 45, 46, 30, 94, 82, 49, 23, 6, 85, 63, 59, 41, 68, 48, 42, 53, 9, 18, 52, 22, 8, 90, 38, 79, 17, 51, 84, 72, 70, 19, 25, 40, 43, 44, 99, 11, 32, 21, 35, 54, 92, 5, 20, 87, 88, 77, 37, 47, 7, 83, 39, 74, 66, 57, 71, 24, 3, 55, 29, 26, 14, 80, 96, 16, 4, 91, 69, 13, 28, 62, 64, 76, 34, 50, 2, 89, 61, 98, 67, 78, 95, 73, 81, 10, 75, 56, 31, 27, 58, 86, 65
2023-12-06 17:20:43,270 DEBUG [ai.tim.sol.cor.imp.loc.DefaultLocalSearchPhase] (main)     LS step (17494), time spent (60091), score (0hard/-20852279soft),     best score (0hard/-20852279soft), accepted/selected move count (1/333), picked move (47 {7} <-tailChainSwap-> 77 {37}).
>>>0, 65, 86, 58, 27, 31, 56, 75, 10, 81, 73, 95, 78, 67, 98, 61, 89, 2, 50, 34, 76, 64, 62, 28, 13, 69, 91, 4, 16, 96, 80, 14, 26, 29, 55, 3, 24, 71, 57, 66, 74, 39, 83, 7, 47, 37, 77, 88, 87, 20, 5, 92, 54, 35, 21, 32, 11, 99, 44, 43, 40, 25, 19, 70, 72, 84, 51, 17, 79, 38, 90, 8, 22, 52, 18, 9, 53, 42, 48, 68, 41, 59, 63, 85, 6, 23, 49, 82, 94, 30, 46, 45, 36, 1, 60, 33, 97, 15, 93, 12
2023-12-06 17:20:43,271 DEBUG [ai.tim.sol.cor.imp.loc.DefaultLocalSearchPhase] (main)     LS step (17495), time spent (60092), score (0hard/-20852279soft),     best score (0hard/-20852279soft), accepted/selected move count (1/65), picked move (12 {0} <-tailChainSwap-> 15 {93}).
>>>0, 12, 93, 15, 97, 33, 60, 1, 36, 45, 46, 30, 94, 82, 49, 23, 6, 85, 63, 59, 41, 68, 48, 42, 53, 9, 18, 52, 22, 8, 90, 38, 79, 17, 51, 84, 72, 70, 19, 25, 40, 43, 44, 99, 11, 32, 21, 35, 54, 92, 5, 20, 87, 88, 77, 37, 47, 7, 83, 39, 74, 66, 57, 71, 24, 3, 55, 29, 26, 14, 80, 96, 16, 4, 91, 69, 13, 28, 62, 64, 76, 34, 50, 2, 89, 61, 98, 67, 78, 95, 73, 81, 10, 75, 56, 31, 27, 58, 86, 65
2023-12-06 17:20:43,272 DEBUG [ai.tim.sol.cor.imp.loc.DefaultLocalSearchPhase] (main)     LS step (17496), time spent (60093), score (0hard/-20852279soft),     best score (0hard/-20852279soft), accepted/selected move count (1/75), picked move (96 {16} <-tailChainSwap-> 14 {80}).
>>>0, 65, 86, 58, 27, 31, 56, 75, 10, 81, 73, 95, 78, 67, 98, 61, 89, 2, 50, 34, 76, 64, 62, 28, 13, 69, 91, 4, 16, 96, 80, 14, 26, 29, 55, 3, 24, 71, 57, 66, 74, 39, 83, 7, 47, 37, 77, 88, 87, 20, 5, 92, 54, 35, 21, 32, 11, 99, 44, 43, 40, 25, 19, 70, 72, 84, 51, 17, 79, 38, 90, 8, 22, 52, 18, 9, 53, 42, 48, 68, 41, 59, 63, 85, 6, 23, 49, 82, 94, 30, 46, 45, 36, 1, 60, 33, 97, 15, 93, 12
2023-12-06 17:20:43,284 DEBUG [ai.tim.sol.cor.imp.loc.DefaultLocalSearchPhase] (main)     LS step (17497), time spent (60105), score (0hard/-20852279soft),     best score (0hard/-20852279soft), accepted/selected move count (1/1267), picked move (1 {60} <-tailChainSwap-> 45 {36}).
>>>0, 65, 86, 58, 27, 31, 56, 75, 10, 81, 73, 95, 78, 67, 98, 61, 89, 2, 50, 34, 76, 64, 62, 28, 13, 69, 91, 4, 16, 96, 80, 29, 26, 14, 55, 3, 24, 71, 57, 66, 74, 39, 83, 7, 47, 37, 77, 88, 87, 20, 5, 92, 54, 35, 21, 32, 11, 99, 44, 43, 40, 25, 19, 70, 72, 84, 51, 17, 79, 38, 90, 8, 22, 52, 18, 9, 53, 42, 48, 68, 41, 59, 63, 85, 6, 23, 49, 82, 94, 30, 46, 45, 36, 1, 60, 33, 97, 15, 93, 12
2023-12-06 17:20:43,285 DEBUG [ai.tim.sol.cor.imp.loc.DefaultLocalSearchPhase] (main)     LS step (17498), time spent (60106), score (0hard/-21033287soft),     best score (0hard/-20852279soft), accepted/selected move count (0/102), picked move (29 {26} <-tailChainSwap-> 14 {80}).
2023-12-06 17:20:43,285 INFO  [ai.tim.sol.cor.imp.loc.DefaultLocalSearchPhase] (main) Local Search phase (1) ended: time spent (60106), best score (0hard/-20852279soft), score calculation speed (111279/sec), step total (17499).
2023-12-06 17:20:43,286 INFO  [ai.tim.sol.cor.imp.sol.DefaultSolver] (main) Solving ended: time spent (60106), best score (0hard/-20852279soft), score calculation speed (111165/sec), phase total (2), environment mode (NON_REPRODUCIBLE), move thread count (NONE).
```

Comment: Would you mind adding the log line entirely? Does it state "after action done"? When [that move.toString](https://github.com/TimefoldAI/timefold-solver/blob/main/core/core-impl/src/main/java/ai/timefold/solver/core/impl/heuristic/selector/move/generic/chained/TailChainSwapMove.java#L338) is called, it's already changed, making it ambiguous indeed. The trouble is that we only want one log message that also includes the score (so after the move is done).

Comment: @GeoffreyDeSmet I added a few last lines of the log, but another one. I didn't save original.